# How to analyze the spectrum of multiple signals?

Tags: python, pytorch

The goal of this analysis is to perform a time-frequency spectrum analysis on a brain wave signal, which is a multi-signal. Despite having prior knowledge and experience in performing a time-frequency spectrum analysis on a single signal, the complexity of the current task requires a more advanced approach. To achieve this, it is necessary to use Python and its various signal processing libraries. It would be greatly appreciated if a sample code could be provided to assist in performing this analysis.

```
import torch

# 脳波信号を読み込む
signal = torch.randn(12, 64000)

# STFTを実行
f, t, Zxx = torch.stft(signal, n_fft=1024, hop_length=512, window=torch.hann_window(1024))

# スペクトルを計算
spectrum = torch.norm(Zxx, dim=0)
```

If there is one signal, it can be done like an RGB image, but I want to do this with multiple signals

Comment: Why not just stack `signal` along the 0th dimension? `num_signal = 12` `signal = torch.randn(num_signal, 64000)`? Is that a valid input for `torch.stft`?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific problem with code you are writing, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Should I stack?